# Manejo de Objetos y Referencias Python

Tags: python, manejo-de-memoria

En python necesito manejar objetos mediante varias referencias. El problema es que al eliminar la Referencia Base que controla (o inició) el objeto queda guardado dicho objeto mediante todas las demas referencias. Me explico con un ejemplo:

```
Materiales = ["Concreto", "Acero", "Madera","Aluminio", "Mamposteria"]
class Elemento:
    self.material = Materiales[0]
    #...mas codigo con otros atributos propios del elemento

#...Otras clases que tienen como atributo una referencia un tipo de material
```

Si de la lista de Materiales borro el material de concreto:

```
del Materiales[0]
```

¿ Como puedo borrar el objeto mismo ?. ¿ En python se puede eliminar el objeto o solo la referencia al objeto ?. Ya manejo lo que son objetos mutables e inmutables y tambien se que Python tiene un recolector manual de basura, pero ¿ es posible por parte del programador eliminar un objeto ?.

Si lo anterior no es posible, entonces cuando se crean objetos y se reasignan referencias o se eliminan referencia de listas, ¿ Se pierde la referencia y por tanto todo objeto creado queda ocupando memoria en ejecucion del programa ?.

Mi idea de manejar multiples referencia es porque puedo modificar una posicion de una lista BASE y el resto de objeto apunten a una posicion de esa variable Lista donde se puede obtener informacion. El problema es cuando elimino posiciones de la Lista BASE y no pretender controlar lo que pase en el resto de objetos que puedan apuntar a esa lista BASE.

Comment: Es un falso problema. En Python los objetos desaparecen cuando ya no los usa. Al contrario de lenguajes primitivos, no necesitas gestionar la memoria.

Answer (score 0):

En Python no es posible eliminar un objeto mientras existan referencias a él.
Al eliminar una referencia, el objeto solo queda inaccesible si ya no hay más referencias a él. Si queres eliminar un objeto completamente, tenes que eliminar todas sus referencias.
Si eliminas una de estas referencias (por ejemplo, al eliminar un elemento de una lista), la otra referencia sigue existiendo y puedes seguir accediendo al objeto.

Edit:
Una forma de evitar que el cambio en la lista base afecte a los objetos que apuntan a ella es crear copias de la información que necesitas en cada objeto.
Por ejemplo, en lugar de almacenar una referencia a un elemento de la lista base en cada objeto, puedes almacenar una copia del elemento:

```
materiales = ["Concreto", "Acero", "Madera", "Aluminio", "Mamposteria"]

class Elemento:
    def __init__(self, indice_material):
        self.material = materiales[indice_material]

# Creas un objeto y le asignas el primer elemento de la lista
objeto1 = Elemento(0)

# creas un objeto y le asignas el tercer elemento de la lista
objeto2 = Elemento(2)

# eliminas el primer elemento de la lista
del materiales[0]

print(objeto1.material)  # Imprime "Concreto"
print(objeto2.material)  # Imprime "Madera"
```

Si luego eliminas un elemento de la lista base, los objetos que ya fueron creados no se verán afectados.

Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Aun tendria un problema.... y es que la idea de crear uns lista BASE es poder modificar los elementos de la lista BASE y que esta sea sólo leida desde otras clases. Es decir, yo quiero modificar el nombre de "Concreto" a "Concreto2" y pueda ser tomada esta informacion desde la Lista BASE. La idea es siempre apuntar a una lista de materiales pero solo para obtener su informacion. Pero si creo copias entonces ya no tendria sentido crear/administrar materiales si al modificarlos no se refleja tal informacion en todos los elementos que se les asigno dicho material.

Comment: De nada! de todas maneras, respondiendo a la pregunta, no es posible eliminar objetos que esten siendo referenciados.

Comment: Lo que tengo pensado hacer es crear un contador del numero de veces que es apuntado un material en particular y si intento eliminar ese material que tiene al menos su contador en 1 (algun elemento tiene ese material) entonces no se puede eliminar. Si un contador esta en cero quiere decir que nadie ha utilizado ese material y puede ser eliminado. Sobre el tema de la memoria que me preocupada estudie un poco mas del recolector de basura de Python y este puede ser ejecutado por el programador o tambien lo ejecuta CPython durante la vida de un programa.